# Install Ubuntu to RAID0 created from "Live" desktop

Tags: boot, grub2, raid

I am booting 14.04 Desktop 64-bit to the "Try" desktop (Live).  In the "Live" boot, I use dmraid to construct a softraid from the two 750GB hard drives on my machine, and then select that when I install Ubuntu.  It goes well until it attempts to install the Grub bootloader.

I've tried a few tutorials on installing the bootloader in this kind of arrangement--e.g., manually creating the partitions, doing chroot to the install and then calling "grub-install", etc.  This never seems to work.  I get one error or another, and it never really sets the install to bootable.  I even tried setting up a fakeraid (my BIOS provides it), but the installer doesn't seem to like it very much.

I'm guessing that this approach isn't even feasible without some serious hacking.  The softraid would not even be active at boot time, so I'm guessing a small, non-raid drive (e.g., SSD) would have to be used to contain the install and then it would build the two larger drives into the softraid after startup.

My question(s) is, then:  Is this even possible, and if so, can somebody point me to a definitive tutorial on setting it up?  I'm not looking to dual-boot (this will be a Linux-dedicated machine), but I would like to have the (only) two drives in the machine in a RAID0 for the entire install.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to install a dedicated [RAID controller (Newegg.com)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124152) and use it instead.  The one in the link is only $20, so it's cheap and easy.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Daniel.  I suspected something like this would pretty much be among the limited options.  Using a small footprint hard drive to act as the RAID controller would be along the same lines.

Comment: Yeah, there's not a whole lot you can do with fake raids, but this is a good compromise.